# How can I macros Word font

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

Why does this VBA code not work? With this normal text.

Unfortunately, my wildcard search is going to find these instances too. Is there a way to find text with different formatting, in a Word macro?

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "~~~" & "[a-zA-Z]" & "~~~"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an accurate problem description. Unfortunately you don't give us an example of the text you're searching, the kind of thing the code should find and what is actually found. Without that information it's unlikely anyone can help you.

Comment: I don't think you are who you're claiming to be in your profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your find replace.

1. You are trying to do a wildcard search without setting the
   .MatchWildcards to True.  We can tell this because you are using a wildcard range [a-xA-Z].

Change

```
.MatchWildcards = False
```

to

```
.MatchWildcards = True
```

and your replace function should work.

The character ranges in the [] need to be in ascending character value order so should be [A-Za-z].  Additionally, to give you more flexibility, you can put brackets around different parts of the find pattern and then refer to these() with \n where n is a sequential number form 1-9.

So your find text would be better expressed as "(~~~)([A-Za-z])(~~~)" and your replacement text as "\1\2\3"

2. You have specified that you want to search on format but don't supply any specific criteria for the find text.  This means that any text that matches your find pattern will be changed to Arial font.

If you only want to change text in the normal style then you will have to specify the style

e.g. add

```
.style = "Normal"
```

Try the changes suggested above and let us know how you get on.

Comment: That's because your original post implied you were looking for a single character surrounded by '~~~'.  If you want to search for any text surrounded by '~~~' then your search text will need to be "(~~~)(*)(~~~)".

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! THANK YOU!